# XML & JAXB: pass attribute into value

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have a large amount of objects generated through JAXB (`maven-jaxb2-plugin`) and annotate them with the `jaxb2-annotate-plugin`. These classes may define a `RelationType` and I'd like to annotate them with the corresponding `@RelationType` annotation. I use an XPath expression to find the name attribute in the XSD and annotate the class, passing its specific type into the annotation. An example of this is the following:

```
<jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='SomeRelationType']">
    <annox:annotate target="class">@com.example.RelationType(type = "SomeRelationType")</annox:annotate>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

which maps on the following XSD snippet:

```
<xsd:complexType name="SomeRelationType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="RelationType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="someValue" type="SomeValue"/>
                <xsd:element name="otherValue" type="OtherValue"/>                     
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I find the ComplexType with the `SomeRelationType` name and annotate the class with a `@RelationType` annotation, which has the `SomeRelationType` as its type parameter. It would generate the following class:

```
@RelationType(type = "SomeRelationType")
public class SomeRelationType extends RelationType implements Serializable {
    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected SomeValue someValue;
    protected OtherValue otherValue;    
}
```

This works fine if it were just a few domain objects. But I have a large amount and defining every annotation manually is not only tedious but also bad in terms of change and expansion.

To generify it, I can rewrite the XPath expression to the following:

```
<jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[substring(@name, string-length(@name) - string-length('RelationType') + 1)]" multiple="true">
    <annox:annotate target="class">@com.example.RelationType(type = "SomeRelationType")</annox:annotate>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

**The problem:** The type parameter of my annotation is still defined as `"SomeRelationType"`. It would be great if I could use the same `@name` as defined in the XPath expression. Then all the classes whose name ends with `"RelationType"` also automatically gets its `@RelationType` annotation with the correct `type` parameter.

It doesn't work as simple as doing the following of course, but it shows what I'd like to achieve:

```
<jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[substring(@name, string-length(@name) - string-length('RelationType') + 1)]" multiple="true">
    <annox:annotate target="class">@com.example.RelationType(type = @name)</annox:annotate>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Is such a thing even possible or is this impossible in XML/JAXB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I have a large amount and defining every annotation manually is not only tedious but also bad in terms of change and expansion.

For me, `@com.example.RelationType(type = "SomeRelationType")` looks like a trivial metainformation which could be derived via reflection without any annotations. So check if there's a way to do "convention over configuration" thing.

The `jaxb2-annotate-plugin` does not and will not support parameterization, it would be too narrow and too complex to implement. **Disclaimer** I'm the author of the [jaxb2-annotate-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin).

I see two options:

- Pre-generate bindings in your build. XML Schema is XML so writing XSLT to produce bindings files should not be too complicated.
- Write an own XJC plugin to add annotations as you want them.
- Bribe me to add parameterization to the [jaxb2-annotate-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin).

Right, just two options.